# How to mount storybook to an angular route?

Tags: angular, angular-router, storybook

I'm hoping to mount storybook into my angular app as a route, I understand it was originally designed as a standalone environment, but I'm looking for a way that allows app and storybook to coexist.

```js
{
  path: 'storybook',
  loadChildren: () => import('./storybook').then(m => m.storybook)
}
```

Comment: reason to close?

Comment: Maybe you need to show how you installed it, and what problem you have. Does that help: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/storybook-for-angular-components-with-markdown-support-72950cc3d9ee?